# Need transparent selections in TListView for Delphi 7 on Windows 7 plus

Tags: delphi, selection, delphi-7, transparent, tlistview

Delphi7 cannot do this by default, but I hope there is a way to do it with some help. My picture shows what I want to do with my ListViews, that transparent selection that allows the colors below to show through it, like the TTreeView does (and does nicely in![enter image description here][1] Delphi7 for some reason).

The site would not let me post a picture because this is my first post. If you look at the listview on the right side of Windows (or File) Explorer, where the files are, especially if you have it in Details view, on Windows 7, Windows 8, you will see the selection bar is kind of transparent. It does not destroy the color of the object (file and file attributes) below it. That's what I need to have. Interestingly, the treeview on the let side, which exhibits the same transparency, is available in Delphi 7's treeview automatically without any special changes. I thought these two components came from the same CommCtrl (or ComCtrls) dll/unit, but the listview doesn't do it in Delphi7 automatically. That is my problem. And OwnerDrawn is not the answer I am hoping for.

Comment: You may want to edit the question because the image is not showing.

Comment: Do you mean the explorer theme, with `SetWindowTheme`.

Comment: I don't see any picture...

Comment: The image does not appear because there is no URL provided for the link.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The problem is that asker is a rep 1 user and as such is not permitted to post images. Only when a user has acquired a degree of trust is she allows to post images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list view control that you are referring to, the one used by Explorer, is not available for third party applications. The list view control used by Explorer is has class name `DirectUIHWND`. The standard system list view is `SysListView32`. The Delphi list view control is `SysListView32`. You cannot host a `DirectUIHWND` control in your Delphi application.

All of which means that if you wish to produce the same type of effect in your application, you will have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the news, not good news, but credible news. And now I can at least stop searching for an answer.